# save entere webpage using ruby (clojure or javascript)

Tags: javascript, ruby, clojure, screen-scraping

I've got a problem. I'm working with a food supplier and I need save the content of each order as html. Orders are listed on a single page as links, but this has 2 difficulties

1. Page uses authentication (need to log me in in advance)
2. This is the real problem: the page use a lot of javascript. Actually everything works without changing the web address so I can't use wget or rio gem (url not like `www.fooddoe.com/order`, `www.fooddoe.com/order/1`, etc. but always like `www.fooddoe.com/suplierx`).

I think firewatir would be a good option but the problem is than I need to save the page in a format similar to html (including images). Is it possible using firewatir? Are there other options in clojure or javascript?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3):

I had to read your question twice to understand what you mean.

From web address from example I assume this is yours supplier web page. So IMHO the easiest way is:

1. Look into source of web page to get an idea how it gets the data (99% for some kind of AJAX request).
2. Request goes to the server which responds to it.
3. Now there are two ways:

   - Get idea how the request is made and write and app to make such request and generate web page with it (more difficult, more general)
   - Contact your supplier and get original database (simpler but one-time solution)

And I think that this is not the question specific to any language.

Comment: If you've managed to understand his question, and it's not too much hassle for you, you have the option to edit his question to make it more readable for anyone else who shows up. As a new user your edit will have to be approved before it's applied, but that's not terribly painful.